# Chrome Remote Desktop - Find Existing PIN

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-remote-desktop

This is a bit of a long shot, but I'm hoping someone might be able to help. A few months ago I setup Chrome Remote Desktop on my work computer, and my home laptop, just on a whim to try it out. I hadn't had a need to use it until this morning, when I suddenly realised that I'd forgotten the PIN. I remember that I used the same PIN on both computers, but for some reason, that completely baffles me, I neglected to record the PIN in my password manager. Is there some way I can view the saved PIN for my home laptop, so that I can use it login to my work computer.

I know I can change the existing PIN, but that's no use, as I need to find out what the current PIN is.

If there is a way to do this, it will save me an otherwise pointless, tedious Saturday morning train trip into the city.

Comment: If there was a way to view the pin, it would make having a pin, sort of useless since anyone with access to the Chrome profile would now have the pin.

Comment: I'm talking about viewing the pin for the local computer that I'm currently using. Not viewing the pin for a remote computer. In this case I just happen to know that the remote pin is the same. Allowing local viewing of the pin wouldn't be a security risk, as a person would have to have physical access to the computer first.

Comment: Note the PIN must be at least 6 digits. I had a similar experience where I had forgotten my PIN and tried all the 4-digit PINs I could remember. As soon as I realized it was minimum 6 digits I was able to recall it.

Answer (score 3):

Go to this link [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://remotedesktop.google.com/access/) and select the edit button where it would give you the option to change your PIN.Alternatively, you could also try to delete the system and add it again.

[image]

Comment: The question does not ask how to change the pin.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you have SSH / terminal access - go to https://remotedesktop.google.com/headless/ and follow the instructions.
This walks you through the steps to create and set a new pin.
(Specifically for your case - you'd then subsequently need to then tell anyone that needs access to the box the pin and problem solved.)

Answer (score 0):

(At least) for the latest web version (remotedesktop.google.com) the pin can be retrieved from the passwords section of the account profile *if* after the initial submission an offer to store the password (=pin) was accepted.

Answer (score -1):

Yes! In the nearly upper right of your chrome browser you will see a circle picture of you or your initials. Left click on it, then you'll see an option called passwords. click that, show passwords. May have to enter your windows password to unlock the passwords visibility.  You can search through your saved passwords from the top center, or Ctrl+f keys to open the search dialog box and enter the possible name on interest such as "remote".  PS to the right of the passwords is the visibility icon of a eye or something :) click that to see what the ******** are.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As far as I can see though, this list is only for website passwords. It doesn't seem to mention anything about the remote desktop pin.

Comment: Chrome Remote Desktop is an ad-on app, which is kind of independent from the browser itself.